# Unbounded sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I was hoping to see if anyone could help me with a thought that I have stumbled upon.

Is there a sequence $a_n$ which is unbounded and its inverse is also unbounded?

I can't think of one myself and I am just looking for some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $a_n=n$ for $n$ even and $a_n=\frac 1 n$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I believe that even if $a_n$ = $n$ was even then yes it would be unbounded but when it is inverted it will still be bounded by the upper bound of 1. And the same goes for n odd. Could you explain more what you are trying to say here .

Comment: The even terms tend to $\infty$ and that makes the sequence itself unbounded. In $(\frac  1{a_n})$ the odd terms tend to $\infty$ and that makes this sequence also unbounded.

Comment: A sequence is unbounded if for every positive constant $C$ , some entry is larger than $C$. The sequence need not be monotonic.

Comment: Sorry im still confused, how is $1/(a_n)$ unbounded when you can choose any number equal or bigger than 1 to be its upper bound?

Comment: The sequence Kavi defines here is defined piecewise depending on the parity of n. I’ll give it as an answer expanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kavi is correctly suggesting in one comment, we can consider

$$a_n=\begin{cases}  n  &\text{ if } n\text{ is even }\\
          \frac{1}{n}  &\text{ if } n \text{ is odd.}\end{cases}$$

Clearly it is unbounded since the even terms are pushing it to infinity.

Its inverse, that we denote $b_n:=\frac{1}{a_n}$, is the same sequence but exchanging the parity of $n$ in the definition. More formally, we have that:

$$b_n=\begin{cases}  n  &\text{ if } n\text{ is odd }\\
          \frac{1}{n}  &\text{ if } n \text{ is even.}\end{cases}$$

Hence it is also unbounded.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you for the more in depth explanation

Comment: Happy to help :)